# sql with employer table? salary and advance_payment

Tags: sql

How to get this payment?

```
employer_payment.payment = employer_salary.salary - employer_advance_payment.advance_payment
```

[image]

Please give me your suggestions on the question how I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  If so, please post it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `LEFT JOIN` to be able to calculate the `salary` deducted by the `advance_payment`.

```
SELECT  a.employerID,
        a.salary - COALESCE(b.advance_payment, 0) payment
FROM    employer_salary a
        LEFT JOIN employer_advance_payment b
            ON a.employerID = b.employerID
```

Comment: thank you. I find also "IIf([b.advance_payment] Is Null,0,[b.advance_payment])" it is equivalent with "COALESCE(b.advance_payment, 0)"